# write <a href> in the jquery code

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, hyperlink, href

A small question. I have an array in a jquery works.
Of this array mold the username of the user and should I use this username in the link, always in the jquery function. Is there a way that allows me to translate this into a normal href a function jquery?
The link I need is this: `<a href:"URL/".id_user> Username </a>`

This is the jquery code:

```
$(".apprezzamenti").click(function()
{    
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.get("http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/apprezzamenti/"+id, 
    function(data)
    { 
        data_parsed = JSON.parse(data);

        for(var i=0; i<data_parsed.length; i++)
        {
            $(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p").append((data_parsed[i].username)).append('<br>');;     
        } 

        $(".chiudi-popup").click(function()
        {
            $(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p").html('');
        });

        $('#main').click(function() 
        {
            $(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p").html('');
        });        
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're appending the username as a text node, so if you want to append an anchor with a href including the user ID, and the username as the text, you can do:

```
$(".modal-body-apprezzamenti>p")
    .append(
        $('<a />', { text : data_parsed[i].username, href : 'URL/' + data_parsed[i].id_user })
    )
    .append($('<br />'));
```

I also changed to append a `<br />` object, rather than raw HTML (minor improvement).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
var user_id = 9; 
var user_name = "Boo";
var link =  $("<a href:"URL/" +  user_id "> " + user_name + " </a>")
$(".your_div").append(link)
```

Just wrap this in your function where and loop through your datas